# Is Coinbase safest exchange?

Tags: security, cryptocurrency

Because Coinbase is regulated more heavily in the US than other non-US or peer-to-peer exchanges, is it considered the safest exchange?

Also, is it ok to leave USD and BTC in Coinbase rather than moving to a paper/desktop/hardware wallet?

Comment: If I had to pick one to trust it would be coinbase....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coinbase is one the user-friendlier exchanges, regulated by choice as much as possible and all in all a good choice. In regards to your question, leaving USD there is alright, leaving cryptocurrency balances though should be avoided for the most part. There are multiple attack vectors to getting access over your Coinbase account that even if coinbase isnt directly responsible the end result may be the same aka loss of your holdings.

Weakest link to it is usually telecom companies that may give access to your phone number to anyone with basic information about you(hijacking your phone 2FA), which in turn can be used to reset your mail information(for confirmation mails) and long story short before you know it your cryptocurrencies are irreversibly lost. This being said Coinbase has its share of issues, since new locations(ip addresses) are not  blocked, by default or by opt-in, of initiating transfers to external addresses.

Paper wallets(make sure to use trusted ones explicitly) or a hardware wallet are your best choices for maximum security. If you consider leaving crypto-funds in your Coinbase account mid to long term at the very least you should consider using the Vault option which enables time-delayed withdrawals for any withdraw request giving you at least time to lock your account in case of a breach.

Comment: Thanks. This is all good to know. I've setup all of my coinbase 2FA and Vault. A few questions: 1.) I'm using an authenticator app for 2FA, which overrides phone/SMS 2FA. Is that best?

2.) About your 2FA phone spoofing comment, how does that work since the code must arrive at my phone # right?

3.) If you are going to deal with an external wallet, wouldn't hardware (i.e., Ledger) be best over a paper wallet? Paper wallets are super tedious and error prone, which risk burning your money.

Comment: Google 2FA ( or similar ) is better than SMS 2FA, so for 1) its a yes.
  Per 2) its called phone porting and you can read up about this in more detail [here](https://www.nextadvisor.com/blog/2018/01/12/phone-porting-how-hackers-can-hijack-your-mobile-phone-number/) And yes you re correct about 3), hardware wallets are the best, yet they come at a cost so a decent alternative is a paper wallet safely generated(preferably offline if possible). Also, just to add on the last part, never ever buy a second hand hardware wallet, only buy new ones from vendors you trust.

Comment: Again, great comments. Than you. Google 2FA is mainly better because it cannot be ported like a phone #?

Comment: @4thSpace no problem, yes its better for this reason. From what I know, they need to go into greater lengths and effort to bypass the Google 2FA by phishing sites posing as the target site and them re-directing the information you provide them ( account details and the 2FA code afterwards) to the original.